# Share Button Like SuperUser

Tags: plugins

I am loving the share buttons on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) and looking forward to find a plugin which has similar share buttons on the right of the post. Any ideas?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unless i missunderstood what you meant those facebook, twitter, google buttons looks
Simple. There are a lot of plugins that allow to pick the services you wish to
disply and also the way that they are shown

**Check out (all sites - not just wordpress):**

1. [addinto.com](http://www.addinto.com/sharebox/)
2. [AddThis](http://www.addthis.com/)

**Wordpress Plugins:**

1. [Facebook, Twitter, Google Plus One social share buttons](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-twitter-google-plus-one-social-share-buttons-for-wordpress/screenshots/)
2. [Slick Social Share](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/slick-social-share-buttons/screenshots/)
3. [Share Buttons Simple Use](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/share-buttons-simple-use/screenshots/)
4. [Addthis for wordpress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/addthis/)
5. [Sharebar](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sharebar/)

.
If you want to build your own design you can easily use simple php scripts
to design "share buttons" with the look and feel suited for your website.

**For Facebook:**

```
<a name="fb_share"></a> 
<script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" 
        type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

(want to style it? visit here: [facebook share button styling](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/))

.

**For Twitter (Put image instead of "Share on Twitte" Text):**

```
<a href=”http://twitter.com/home?status=Currently reading <?php the_permalink(); ?>” title=”Click to share this post on Twitter”>Share on Twitter</a>
```

.

**For Google Plus (Put image instead of "Google +1" Text):**

```
<a id="plusone-icon" class="pngfix" style="margin-left: -17px;" title="PlusOne" href="https://plusone.google.com/_/ +1/confirm?hl=en&url=<?php if (is_home()) { echo site_url(); } else {  echo the_permalink(); } ?>">Google +1</a>
```

(Source: [Custom Google Plus One Button](http://davidvielmetter.com/tricks/custom-google-plus-one-button/))

.
Hope this helps ;)
Sagive.

Comment: Actually.I am looking for an exact copy of the the plugin I described. Thankyou for the answer. It is very descriptive. I think I will have to edit a plugin to make required changes to it.

Comment: i dont think there is a ready "just like that" plugin.. why not write your own code then simply call the function where and when you need it... isnt it the best way? dont know if you should use their icons <-- you know - copyrighs etc..